# Tail for Powershell v3?

Tags: powershell, tail, powershell-3.0

I'm running the following command in my powershell terminal:

```
Get-Content C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.22\logs\lysol-dbau.access.log -Tail 10 -Wait
```

So I want to start with the last 10 lines of the file and then display changes as they occur.  However, log display is not updating, even when the log file is being updated by Apache.  Thoughts?  Should this be working?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4426442/unix-tail-equivalent-command-in-windows-powershell

Comment: Kind of a useless comment seeing as I did exactly that, and implemented the use of Tail as is explained at the very bottom of that page.

Comment: I think the command you show should work. It could have something to do with how apache is flushing the log to disk.